# Remarriage after divorce

Tags: texas, marriage, divorce

I just had a question about remarrying after a divorce. Is it legally required to show a divorce decree at the time of remarriage? Also how would it effect the marriage registration if one didn't present the divorce decree? P.S I'm talking about the Laws in the United States of America specifically the state of Texas

Comment: Marriages are handled by states, not by the federal government, so you'll need to specify your state.  But you may get a faster answer just by contacting whatever agency handles marriage licensing in your town, and reading about their procedure and documents.

Comment: Thank you will do